# An HTTP request to "m.google.com" never makes it out of my home network

Tags: networking, iphone, dns, wireless-router, google-sync

I'm trying to call up "https://m.google.com" on my iPhone on my home WiFi. It's saying Safari "cannot verify server identity" of m.google.com, then when I press Details, it refers to https://m.google.com as "mattserver". "mattserver" is the name of my development server, a Linux box on my home network. This stinks of DNS issues to me. Accessing the unsecure version of that URL ("http://m.google.com") gives me a blank page.

What could be going on here? Is there a way to look at the logs of my router somehow?

**EDIT**: I just found that my dev server shows the same symptoms. When I go to m.google.com from there, it says I'm connecting to 192.168.0.2, which is my dev server's IP.

My workstation is not showing symptoms, probably because it uses [Acrylic DNS Proxy](http://mayakron.altervista.org/support/browse.php?path=Acrylic&name=Home).

**EDIT (Went deeper into the problem)**

Within my home network, requesting "m.google.com" gets me 192.168.0.2, which is my dev server. When I do an nslookup to try and weed out this [I think] DNS issue, it says this: "192.168.0.1: Non-existant domain". 192.168.0.1 is my router.

[image]

Comment: For those who think this is off-topic: **Please read the question again**. It's probably not a problem with the iPhone, the iPhone just shows the symptoms. (:

Comment: But does anything else show the symptom?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson That's the question! ;) of course, this could turn off topic if it is indeed an iPhone issue. But superficially, this looks like a networking/DNS issue... I just don't like people closing to vote the moment they see the word "iPhone"

Comment: Can you replicate the symptoms on any other clients attached to the router?

Comment: @chunkyb2002 I just found that my dev server shows the same symptoms. See First edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure exactly what the problem was with that specific domain, but when I removed a rogue entry in my routers' "DNS Host Mapping" list, it all ended up working again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check in the settings app to see what your DNS server is... Then go to your PC and set its DNS server to be the same as your iPhone and run an NSLOOKUP and see what's happening.

If your DNS Server is your router, just try pulling the plug on the router and rebooting it, this fixes more problems than people care to admit. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the right DNS servers on your clients, two options:

- Set the DNS servers to external ones.
- Set the DNS server to your development server, which should have forwarders set to the external.

You can do this in two ways:

- Static, by filling it directly.
- Dynamic, set the DHCP server (either your router or server) to distribute the right DNS servers.

Basically, what happens now:

- Your clients are configured to contact your Development server for DNS information.
- A request is made to your DNS server hosted on the Development server.
- If you have a DNS server then it responds with its own IP as no forwarders are set.